# Web programming Python powershell error

Tags: python, web

I'm new to python and I have just started web development. In the tutorial there is a page where I print out "hello world" using windows `powershell`. [But I have been keep getting this message and cannot access to local host :( please help me)

```
[error notice][1]
PS C:\Users\Administrator> python ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py’ \Downloads\helloworld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1040, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 1033, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 758, in start
    options.config_paths, options.app_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 831, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(config_path, app_id)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 127, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 423, in _parse_configuration
    with open(configuration_path) as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Downloads\\helloworld'
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Answer (score 0):

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\Downloads\helloworld'

1) **\Downloads\helloworld** folder exists?

2) are you using good path to folder?